# Wireless not working with BCM4311 - not attached to wlan0

Tags: wireless, broadcom

New to Linux. I have a Broadcom BCM4311 Wi-Fi card. The Wi-fi was working after installing the B43 drivers, but has stopped working. For some reason it's now not attached to WLAN0.

I don't have an ethernet cable, but I have a Windows machine connected to the net via wireless. Ubuntu version 12.10.

```
$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
Ethernet controller : Broadcom NetXtreme    BCM5788 Gigabit Ethernet [14e4:169c]
Network Controller : Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312]

$ lshw -c network -short
H/W path         Device       Class    Description
/0/100/6/0                    network    BCM4311 802.11a/b/g
/0/100/14.4/1    etho         network    NetXtreme BCM5788 Gigabit Ethernet
/1               wlan0        network    Wireless interface
```

Not sure if the following would help:

```
$ lsmod | grep b43
b43            347364    0
mac80211       461261    1  b43
cfg80211       175574    2  b43,mac80211
bcma           34484     1 b43
ssb            50088     2 b43,ssb_hcd
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

Run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If the command run successfully try to switch on wireless (with the hardware key).

If it doesn't work or the command failed saying there is no such module, then you could try opening a terminal and type

```
dmesg | grep b43
```

If you see lines like:

```
[   17.453421] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode15.fw" not found
[   17.453427] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode15.fw" not found
[   17.453432] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
[   17.680077] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 478.104 (2008-07-01 00:50:23)
[   17.993040] b43-phy0: Radio hardware status changed to DISABLED
```

Now you probably are lacking the firmware for the Broadcom card. Open Software Center, search and install the following packages,

- b43-fwcutter
- firmware-b43-lpphy-installerer

Reboot once. Now the wireless should work.

Comment: If this is Ubuntu 18.04LTS, you can remove the bcmwl driver from the "Software&Updates" > "Additional Drivers" > "Broadcom Limited: BCM4311" > "Do not use the device".   Apply Changes. Reboot to purge the loaded driver.